# eventDrop callback in Full Calendar does not work in react unless inspect/console is open on browser

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fullcalendar, event-drops

i have a function that updates "booking" collection in firestore. this function is linked to Full Calendar callback but the function is only triggered when inspect/console is open on browser

the function that updates the calendar events :

```
const handleEventUpdate = async (info) => {
console.log("info", info); 
// Ask for confirmation before updating the event
const confirmation = window.confirm(
  "Are you sure you want to update this event ?"
);

if (confirmation) {
  try {
    // Make a PUT request to update the start and end times using bookingId
    await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:5000/bookings/update/${info.event.extendedProps.bookingId}`,
      {
        start: moment(info.event.start).toISOString(),
        end: moment(info.event.end).toISOString(),
      }
    );

    // Log a success message
    console.log("Event update request sent successfully");
    // Log a success message
    console.log("Event updated successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error updating event:", error);
  }
} else {info.revert();}
};



Calendar Options of Full Calendar:
 const calendarOptions = {
 allDaySlot: false,
 plugins: [timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
 initialView: "timeGridWeek",
 events: events,
 eventOverlap: false,
 droppable: isEditMode,
 editable: isEditMode, // Set to true only for clients
 ** eventDrop: handleEventUpdate,
 eventResize: handleEventUpdate,**
 .
 }
```